# Application won't render data on first run - R Studio

Tags: shiny, rstudio

I have a data profiling application that accepts some Excel data files and renders data in a datatable. A very simple app developed in R Studio using Shiny in R Studio. The app runs on my local dev machine.

I am facing a peculiar problem - when I run the app from R-studio for the first time and load the file, the app runs through all the code but nothing is rendered on screen.

If I quit the application(not R Studio - just close the app) and run it again 
- now it runs just fine !

This happens consistently on every first run of the app. I have no errors,warnings of any other such info in the console in R Studio. Also I can see that all the right code paths have been executed since I have put in "print" messages at all the points from which data has to return / render.

I am wondering if anybody has faced first run issues in R Studio - could it be a memory issue or something - a bug in R Studio  ? Any pointers are much appreciated.

Comment: If run this example: `runExample("09_upload")` do you have same problem?

Comment: I was not able to run that "09_upload" but other examples run fine ...

Comment: Ok The issue was with the DT library ! Found the answer here :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31683429/r-shiny-dt-strange-rendering-issue